# Kill Java Process after Completing Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method

Tags: java

I  am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute `shell` script on `linux` environment but I am seeing that java process does not killing after completing this task. How to **stop/kill** java process after completing this task.

Java

```
private class Task implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{shellfile}, null, new File(shellfilepath));
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {

        };

    }
```

Comment: There is no evidence that you even try to wait for the task to complete.

Comment: you could call `Process#destroy`

Comment: Are you trying to kill the Java process that is executing the shell script? Or are you trying to kill a new Java process executed from the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. You can block until the task completes by using `Process#waitFor`

```
class Task implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{shellfile}, null, new File(shellfilepath));
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // handle the error
        }
    };
}
```

If you think the program might hang you could wrap `waitFor` in a `Thread` and `join` with a timeout. After the timeout you can call `destroy` on the process.

```
class Task implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{shellfile}, null, new File(shellfilepath));
            final Thread thread = new Thread(process::waitFor);
            thread.start();
            thread.join(1000);
            process.destroy();
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // handle the error
        }
    };
}
```